# How can I insert a set of records in an Access table which come from an aggregate query

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

MS Office 365 ProPlus, Access 2007 - 2016

I'm trying to insert a set of records into a table using an insert statement feeding out of a select statement.  Here is what I'm trying...

```
insert into BurnDownMetrics
  (day,project,domain,tot_effort_spent,tot_effort_left,tot_est_effort)
SELECT Date() AS Expr1, 
       ardmerspk.project, 
       ardmerspk.domain, 
       Sum(ardmerspk.effort_spent) AS SumOfeffort_spent, 
       Sum(ardmerspk.effort_left) AS SumOfeffort_left, 
       Sum(ardmerspk.tot_effort) AS SumOftot_effort
FROM ardmerspk
GROUP BY ardmerspk.project, ardmerspk.domain;
```

The subquery alone (the "SELECT Date() ...") works great when I test this in a "Create Query Design".  It returns the set of about 20 records exactly as I would expect.  But when I try to feed that into the insert statement, it inserts one row only.

The "Date()" col is a bit unusual.  But it doesn't seem to bother the query when that is run alone.

Any idea what's wrong with this ?

Comment: Don't know if causing an issue, but Day and Domain are reserved words and should avoid using reserved words as names for anything. Enclose in `[ ]` in the fields array `([day],project,[domain]…)`. Otherwise, see nothing wrong with SQL. Syntax works for me.

Comment: Nope, no luck.  What's weird is that it does manage to insert one record.  If it was a syntax problem, you'd think it would croak before doing even that.  I saw neither "day" nor "domain" as reserve words for access here... https://support.office.com/en-us/article/learn-about-access-reserved-words-and-symbols-ae9d9ada-3255-4b12-91a9-f855bdd9c5a2

Comment: Cannot replicate issue. Review this list http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html. Day is an intrinsic VBA function. Domain has other special meanings.

Comment: You don't even get a message that insert failed? No fields are set as unique?

Comment: No messages.  There are no unique (primary key) fields in that table, but there is a combo of fields that are unique (I would think this shouldn't matter).  It DOES insert one record though.  The subquery run alone returns a couple dozen records.

Comment: *I saw neither "day" nor "domain" as reserve words for access here... support.office.com/en-us/article/…*  `Ctrl+F` when viewing that page and you'll find them.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data for which the query fails?

Comment: If Ctrl+F doesn't work, click on "Access database engine reserved words" or scroll down the page.

Comment: Ah, there was another list of reserve words under the first set that I didn't look at.  I see them now.

Comment: Actually, the query doesn't fail.  It returns a couple dozen records just as I would expect.  But it inserts only one (the first) record.  Very odd.  I'm wondering if it has to do with the fact that the first column in the select statement... "Day" is not in the "group by" statement.    I'll run an experiment to see if that's the cause.