# How can msaccess be run in the background without the gui

Tags: ms-access

I have a macro in MSACESS that I want to run as a scheduled task, without a gui and any confirmation windows that pop up.  The macro inserts records into a table.  This is what it looks like...

```
Public Sub Update_Burndown_Metrics()

    Dim SQL_Text As String
    Dim CurrDate As String

    CurrDate = DateValue(CStr(Now()))

    SQL_Text = "insert into BurnDownMetrics (project, domain, tot_effort_spent, tot_effort_left, tot_est_effort, when_captured) select project, domain, sum(effort_spent), sum(effort_left), sum(tot_effort), '" & CurrDate & "' from tasks group by project,domain"

    DoCmd.SetWarnings (False)
    DoCmd.RunSQL SQL_Text
    DoCmd.SetWarnings (True)

End Sub
```

This macro works fine when run interactively in an Access session.  It also runs fine when I run it from a .bat like this...

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\MSACCESS.EXE" \\Somewhere\Somewhere_else\tdb.accdb /cmd Update_Burndown_Metrics
```

The one caveat in this mode is that a window pops up asking me if I really want to insert the records. The answer to that will always be "yes".

Now, I want to run the .bat as a scheduled task.  I do not want the gui and I don't want the pop-up.  Can this be done ?

I tried sticking "Application.Visible = False" in the macro.  Didn't work. I think this may be for ExCel only?

Comment: Use `CurrentDb.Execute` instead of `RunSQL`. Won't even need the SetWarnings lines. I do wonder why the confirmation popup is not suppressed. Also, are you saving CurrDate into a text field? If it is actually a date/time field, should use `#` delimiter instead of apostrophe. Point of detail, this is VBA not a macro. Macros in Access are very different.

Comment: I must confess up front that I'm a linux guy, not windows.  A bit (lot) like a fish out of water.     So are you saying that if I replace "DoCmd.RunSQL" with "DoCmd.CurrentDb.Execute" the popup will be surpressed ?      Yes, it is a date field.  The "CurrDate" was something I found googling around.  I was so pleased with myself when this actually worked, however it worked.  I tried/failed to use "now()" in the insert command, but since that cmd used aggregates, it didn't work, so I resorted to this.   Not sure what you mean (specifically... remember  I'm a linux guy) when you say # delimited.

Comment: If you make `Date()` the *Default Value* for `BurnDownMetrics.when_captured`, you won't need to supply that value with your `INSERT`.  The db engine will do it for you automagically.

Comment: You can also try removing the brackets from your DoCmd.SetWarnings (False) command.  In VBA, arguments for subs do not need brackets.  So, it would be DoCmd.SetWarnings False

Comment: The parentheses don't make a difference in this case.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what CurrDate is nor why it would work for you. It is not an intrinsic function in VBA nor Access SQL. If you want today's date, use Date(); if you want date and time, use Now(). There is a CurDate() function in MySQL but Access SQL engine will not recognize that one either.

CurrentDb does not need the DoCmd prefix.

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO BurnDownMetrics (project, domain, tot_effort_spent, " & _
                  "tot_effort_left, tot_est_effort, when_captured) " & _
                  "SELECT project, domain, Sum(effort_spent), " & _
                  "Sum(effort_left), Sum(tot_effort), Date() " & _
                  "FROM tasks GROUP BY project, domain"
```

Example VBScript that opens Access db object and runs VBA or macro procedure. The Access app window will not display but it will show in Windows taskbar.

```vb
Set accessApp = CreateObject("Access.Application")
accessApp.OpenCurrentDataBase "C:\Users\LL\Umpires.accdb"
'accessApp.UserControl = true
accessApp.Visible = False
accessApp.Run "TestVBA"
'accessApp.DoCmd.RunMacro "TestMacro"
accessApp.Quit
```

Thanks to @HansUp suggestion, found another approach https://rtmccormick.com/2014/06/05/how-to-connect-to-access-database-with-vbscript/. Example VBScript:

```vb
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cn.open = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=C:\Users\LL\Umpires.accdb"
cn.execute "INSERT INTO Rates(RateID,RateLevel) VALUES('zz','zz')"
```

As advised in the link, had to run the script from a shortcut with Target property modified:
`%windir%\SysWoW64\wscript.exe C:\Users\LL\RunProc.vbs`

Comment: I'll give this a try tomorrow.  Question first.... are you sure abou tthe unmatched single quotes that appear before 2 of the "accessApp." statements ?  I really doon't know this language, but the fact that they appear to be unmatched is suspicious (to me anyway).

Comment: Those apostrophes cause the lines to comment and will not execute. This is the same in VBA. I left the lines in just for information.

Comment: How does one run VBA code outside of an application, like Access ?    I tried just creating another vba sub in the same module that I had "Update_Burndown_Metrics", but then just invoked it the same way I did before in the .bat, which just invoked Access first.  From looking at your code, it looks like it's invoking Access, no need/desire for me to.  So the question now is, how does one run vba from a .bat ?   Thanks for the help BTW :-)

Comment: OK, I think I'm getting closer.  I managed to create a vbs script on the Desktop.  When I run it, I get an error "Microsoft Access cannot find the procedure" which sounds like a contexting issue.  The vba sub inside Access is called "Update_Burndown_Metrics" which is inside a Module.  To be honest, I don't know what the module is named but when I bring it up in design view, the banner at the top has "Update_Burndown_Metrics (Code)".  If this is contexting, how to I properly identify the sub ?

Comment: Module and procedure cannot have same name. Rename the module.

Comment: VBScript can use ADO or DAO to execute an `INSERT`.  No need to start a full MSACCESS.EXE application session.

Comment: I renamed the module to UBM_Code and tried again.  Same error.   Can/should the VBA  subroutine move out of Access altogether ?    I tried sticking it in the vbs script but that didn't work

Comment: That should work but might be able to accomplish completely within VBScript. See revised answer. Edit question with VBScript code if still need help.

Comment: Does make me wonder how the .bat file could have worked if module and sub had same name.

Comment: That one gave... "Provider cannot be found.  It may not be properly installed"... "Source: ADODB.Connection".   I don't have OLE.  I don't think I can do ADO.   I just a DB on a file server.           I tried creating a macro in the DB that does the same thing.  works fine when I call it.  Renamed the vba module and sub to something else to avoid confusion.  That failed too, same error, can't find the procedure.

Comment: FINALLY I got it to work.  My bad.  There was another module with a sub by the same name.  So embarrassed.  Thanks Everyone for all the help !

Answer (score 0):

Where the SQL is concerned, you can evaluate the `Date()` function directly from the query, i.e.:

```sql
insert into BurnDownMetrics (project, domain, tot_effort_spent, tot_effort_left, tot_est_effort, when_captured) 
select project, domain, sum(effort_spent), sum(effort_left), sum(tot_effort), Date()
from tasks
group by project, domain
```

Furthermore, if you are populating **all** of the fields in the `BurnDownMetrics` in the order in which they appear in the table, then the query can be reduced further to:

```sql
insert into BurnDownMetrics
select project, domain, sum(effort_spent) as tot_effort_spent, sum(effort_left) as tot_effort_left, sum(tot_effort) as tot_est_effort, Date() as when_captured
from tasks
group by project, domain
```

Your Sub can then become:

```vb
Public Sub Update_Burndown_Metrics()
    With CurrentDb
        .Execute _
        "insert into BurnDownMetrics (project, domain, tot_effort_spent, tot_effort_left, tot_est_effort, when_captured) " & _
        "select project, domain, sum(effort_spent), sum(effort_left), sum(tot_effort), Date() " & _
        "from tasks " & _
        "group by project, domain"
    End With
End Sub
```

This should then no longer warn you about inserting records.

---

As for suppressing the GUI, I'm not sure that this is possible: the method that I typically follow is as described by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20251788/7531598).

Comment: I tried putting the date() function (or something similar) directly in the SQL as you suggested. For some reason it didn't work.  I think it has something to do with the aggregate functions, so I googled around, found the CUrrDate somewhere and glued it into a string.  Seems to have worked, hacky as it is.        I don't think it's reliable to assume column order when doing something like an insert, or even a query.  Simply changing a property of a column can rearrange things.   I know this to be true for other, non-Access DBs anyway.  But maybe Access works differently.

Comment: Could you elaborate on: *"For some reason it didn't work"* Did you receive an error message? If so, what was it? Are you inserting the data into a field of `Date/Time` type? From your example it looks like you are populating a text field with date data, which is very bad practice. I agree that the order of fields should not be relied upon, hence why I offered both options.

Comment: I actually posted something on this... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54488047/how-can-i-insert-a-set-of-records-in-an-access-table-which-come-from-an-aggregat